# Yii2 - hasOne alternative

Tags: database, activerecord, yii2

In Yii2 we get [related models](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord#hasOne()-detail) using

```
class AnyClass {
    ...
    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(User::className(), ['id' => 'user_id']);
    }
}
```

What's the difference to this implementation?

```
class AnyClass {
    ...
    public function getUser()
    {
        return User::find()->where(['id' => $this->user_id]);
    }
}
```

I plan to use multiple compound keys and think the second version is much easier to extend with additional conditions for compound keys.

Comment: Why do you think that second version is  easier to extend for compound keys?

Comment: I can supply arguments for e.g. ```getUser($onlyAdults=true)``` and extend the ActiveQuery with ```->andWhere(['adult'=>1])```. Or I can supply additional indices for the compound keys.

Comment: Still don't get it. You can do the same with `hasOne()` result. Could you give any example (as a code sample) what you want to do with relation and which is unavailable when you're using `hasOne()`?

Comment: You can obtain the same result  .. but if you are using a framework  why you don't want use the function that this framwork  make available  .. then you can also avoid a framwork and build proper function based on PDO  .. or others  .

Comment: `AnyClass::find()->joinWith('user'=>function($q){$q->where(['{{%user}}.[[adult]]'=>1])})->all()` will do that too

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add compound keys or extra conditions in the relation itself:

```
public function getUser() {
    return $this->hasOne(User::className(), ['id' => 'user_id'])
       ->onCondition(['user.status' => 'active'])
}
public function getAdultUser() {
    return $this->getUser()->where(['user.adult' => 1])
}
```

Also keep in mind that the actual related records are loaded when you call it trough the getter method:

- `$anyClass->user` will return an instance of **User**.
- `$anyClass->getUser()` will return the **ActiveQuery** object.

So you can add extra conditions when and where you need them:

```
$anyClass->getUser()->where(['>', 'user.created_at', strtotime("previous month")])
```

---

Your implementation does not represent an actual relation between the two objects. It will work **ONLY** for lazy-loading data **AND IF** `AnyClass` is a loaded record: `AnyClass::findOne(1)->user`.

The only way to mange aggregate data or multiple results sets, where lazy-loading is impractical, is by using **hasOne** or **hasMany**, and specify the logical relation between your tables (in this case `['id' => 'user_id']` refers to the strict relation between `AnyClass` and `User`).

```
AnyClass::find()->with(`user`)->limit(1000); 
AnyClass::find()->joinWith(`user`);
SomeOtherClass::find()->joinWith('anyClass.user')->where('user.is_valid');
```